# Issue with sending message to Slack when cell automatically update

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, slack

I am new to coding and app script. I am trying to send a message to Slack when the cell is updated, in this can I want the message to send to slack when the checkbox value changes.

I am not sure if I can change the var availability to something else that would show the value of the formula.

```
function sendSlackMessage(e) {

if(e.range.getColumn() == 2) {
  var source = e.source;
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var column = e.range.getColumn();
  var stall = source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
  var date = source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 3, 1, 1).getValue();
  var availability = e.value;


  var url = "";
  var payload = {
    text: "Stall #" +" "+ stall + " " +  "is" + " " +   availability
  }

var headers = {
  'Content-type': 'application/json'
}
var options = {
  headers: headers,
  method: 'POST',
  payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
}

UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}else {
return;
}

}
```

[image]

I have tried to `setValue`, and `getDisplayValue` but those didnt work.

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I am not sure if I can change the var availability to something else that would show the value of the formula.` and `but those didnt work.`. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Currently my availability value is set to e.value. but it when the value of that cell changes automatically it won't send the message to slack. However, when i manually change the value of that cell it would send message to slack. I was wondering if i have to change the e.value to something else to make that work whenever the cell updates automatically. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. IN your situation, how is your function `sendSlackMessage` executed? If you are using a trigger, can I ask you about the detail of the trigger?

Comment: Can you share a sample/copy of your spreadsheet? Remove sensitive data if any. Also how is the cell is being updated? Sorry for the confusion from the post your question is `I am not sure if I can change the var availability to something else that would show the value of the formula.` If I understood it correctly you are saying the the var availability is currently getting the formula instead of the actual value, but in your comment you are saying `but it when the value of that cell changes automatically it won't send the message to slack` not sure which is your current issue.

Comment: Hello please see below for the document.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jBCJfRMxpfIQU7PeJ0zmceM0fidQpSHeqj4qWvEDL0U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry please clarify your current issue as per my previous comment. Also as per Tanaike's comment, are you using a trigger?

Comment: Hello yes i am using trigger. The current issue is that whenever the cell (B) automatically updates, It wont send the message to slack. However, whenever I manually change the status of the checkbox it will send the message to slack.

Comment: Please provide more details on your trigger. Most likely it is causing the issue. @adavoodi

Comment: Hello, the trigger is on edit event type. I have attached the photo above too. Thank you for your help.

Comment: From your statement `when the value of that cell changes automatically it won't send the message to slack.` How is it being updated automatically? @adavoodi

Comment: it is formula on cell B, whenever someone adds a date (Cell C), the checkbox in cell B get unchecked. and whenever someone add date out (cell D). cell B checkbox gets a checkmark.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, based on my understanding from our discussion I have posted an answer. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have questions. @adavoodi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code only runs when you edit the sheet manually using the checkbox is because your script is inside a condition `if (e.range.getColumn() == 2)` which means it is only running if you edit on **column B**. So if you make edits on other columns it just returns since your else statement catches it.

```
}else {
return;
}
```

How about removing this condition and add the following instead, so if you edit other columns it will run and the **availability** you will get is still the value from column B whether you edit **Column B, Column C, or Column D**:

```
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 2) {
    var availability = e.value;
  } if (e.range.getColumn() == 3) {
    var availability = source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, column - 1, 1, 1).getValue();
  } else if (e.range.getColumn() == 4) {
    var availability = source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, column - 2, 1, 1).getValue();
  }
```

### Full revised code:

**Try:**

```
function sendSlackMessage(e) {

  var source = e.source;
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var column = e.range.getColumn();
  var stall = source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
  var date = source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 3, 1, 1).getValue();

  //Get Availability
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 2) {
    var availability = e.value;
  } if (e.range.getColumn() == 3) {
    var availability = source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, column - 1, 1, 1).getValue();
  } else if (e.range.getColumn() == 4) {
    var availability = source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, column - 2, 1, 1).getValue();
  }

  var url = "https://hooks.slack.com";
  var payload = {
    text: "Stall #" + " " + stall + " " + "is" + " " + availability
  }

  var headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
  }
  var options = {
    headers: headers,
    method: 'POST',
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
  }

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

}
```